# Spring Security: Handling BOTH web app security and web service security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Is it possible to create conditions in the Spring Security configuration to prevent the login form from being displayed if user doesn't have access to certain URI pattern?

I have the following configuration right now:-

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/" authentication-failure-url="/?login_error=1" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_WEBSERVICE"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
</security:http>
```

This is what I want Spring Security to handle:-

1. When user hits `/secure/**` without proper access from a browser, a login form should be displayed. This configuration satisfies this requirement.
2. When user hits `/api/**` without proper access, throw a 403 error instead of displaying the login form. The reason is because the user may programmatically invoke the web services from javascript or using curl and it doesn't make sense to return the HTML source code of the login form in the response.
3. Use will call `/api/login` to authenticate themselves before they can use other `/api` web services.

I have been building this web app using Spring Security and it has been working just fine. However, right now, I need to be able to expose some of the functionalities through web services and I'm having a hard time trying to secure both my web app and my web services using Spring Security.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define [multiple filter chains](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#filter-chains-with-ns) based on the pattern of the incoming request path and use that to separate the web-service part from browser access.

For the `/api` filter chain you would define an `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint` and set that as the `entry-point-ref` attribute:

```
<http pattern="/api/**" entry-point-ref="forbiddenEntryPoint">
   ...
</http>

<http>
   ... standard form-login etc., as you have now
</http>

<bean id="forbiddenEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />
```